# rails hiding Employees entrance password from git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm building a app that only a company Employees can use 
when the employee is signing up they will fill in two passwords there own and the company's

```
 def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if params[:company_password] != 'password'
    flash.now[:notice] = "company password incorrect "
    render 'new'
elsif @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to root_path
else
    render 'new'
end
end
```

I don't want the company password to be exposed is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Development and Test ENV.

```
gem "figaro"

bundle exec figaro install
```

It will generate `config/application.yml` file, also `.gitignore` line (to not push `KEYS`).

## config/application.yml

```
COMPANY_PASSWORD: "password"
COMPANY_KEY: "password"
```

Now you can use it anywhere in an app to use key `ENV["COMPANY_PASSWORD"]`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an environment variable:

```
if params[:company_passwod] != ENV['COMPANY_PASSWORD]
```

When you deploy it, run a Rails console on Heroku to set the password:

```
ENV['COMPANY_PASSWORD'] = 'yolo'
```

Comment: thanks is there a good place to set ENV['COMPANY_PASSWORD'] for development and testing?

Comment: If you're using Rails 4.1 or later you can use the secrets.yml file in config/, otherwise you can Google various options for using older versions of Rails.